# Python - how to read the remainder of a string after a match has been found

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to be able to find a second match within serial data using the re.search method. So far I've been able to use the re.search regular expression to find the first match.

How would I go about looking for the letters PR and print the digits to the right of it after finding the first match in the same serial string?

The code below shows connection to a device through a COM port.
Stores the data to serial and looks for the digits to the right of the word 'ID' on the same line.

serial data: aassddffggID:12345qqwweerrttPR:54321zzxxxcc

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 115200, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=0)
print(ser)
time.sleep(0.5)
serial = ser.read(9999)

match = re.search('ID:(\d*)', serial)
print(match.group(0))
```

**Update:**

I would like to modify this re.search to allow parameters to be passed to ID and PR. I have been able to pass a value to ID but can't seem to get values passed to both without error.

This bit works...

id = 12345
pr = 54321

```
if re.search(r"ID:{}".format(id), serial)
    print("ID match found")
else:
    print("ID match not found")

#output
"ID match found"

#For both ID and PR I've tried
if re.search(r"ID:{}".format(id)."PR:{}".format(pr), serial)
    print("PR match found")
else:
    print("PR match not found")

#output
"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

Note. It doesn't like the inverted commas after curly brackets have closed after PR:{}

Any suggestions on changes to the syntax?

Comment: Use `.group(1)`, the value is captured by Group 1, or just run `re.findall` and grab `[1]` item. `.group(0)` contains the whole match value.

Comment: `match = re.search('ID:(\d+).*?PR:(\d+)', s)` and then use `match.group(1)` and `match.group(2)`

Comment: @anubhava the lazy quantifier is not needed here

Comment: @Adirio: It won't harm or change the match results and depending upon input length it might be more efficient as well

Comment: Exactly, one depends on the number of chars from the ID to the PR and the other from the PR to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match = re.search(r'ID:(\d+).*PR:(\d+)', serial)
```

`match.group(1)` will be your first match and `match.group(2)` will be the numbers after `PR:`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an regex to mach all two uppercase letters and the `findall()` method.

Would be something like this:

```
    match = re.findall('[A-Z]{2}:(\d*)', serial)
```

It will return to you a list with all matches or None if nothing is found.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall